# Issue with border-radius and one thicker border issue in Webkit

Tags: css, colors, webkit, border

Alright, well I have searched and searched on google, stackoverflow, other sites for an issue regarding how webkit handles the combination of border-radius, border width and color applied to a box, with one side having both a thicker border and different border-color.

I have been testing and testing both in the project I'm currently working on and in JSfiddle.

I have created a JSfiddle with multiple test cases in it exemplifying what styles do and do not affect this bug. http://jsfiddle.net/kGST9/4/

You will see that most of the boxes have a strip of red in the centers of the top and bottom borders. You'll also notice that on the different test cases the width of the strip of red varies depending from what I've found, on the width of the left border and the width of the box. I believe it truly doesn't matter what side the thicker border is on and will behave the same. This only occurs in webkit, both the latest releases of Safari 5 and Chrome 16, and I'm assuming this goes to all versions of webkit that supports border radius.

Firefox does not display this issue.

I have not even been able to find anyone talking about this bug in a forum or blogpost, and do not believe to be the only to have this problem. lol

Just for reference, I've also attempted adding other none border related styles, such as position, display, overflow, background-clip, and their various values, with none of them helping.

So help me get down to the bottom of this if you will.

Regards,
CSSDevMonkey

Comment: Definitely consider filing a bug report.

Comment: bug report has been filed with Webkit already back on Nov 11 of last year, I added a comment with my test cases, of which I have updated them: http://jsfiddle.net/kGST9/8/

Answer (score 0):

Very strange indeed. I've found after toying with it that whether or not the bug shows up (and how severe it is) is tied to a combination of the ratio of the box's overall width and height as well as the size of the border radius. I can get the problem to go away (in all but one case) by increasing the border radius to 20px. Also, reducing the width of every div to 200px seems to fix the issue.

Definitely looks like a bug. Not sure what a direct fix would be other than playing with varying width/height ratios, border-radii, or border widths. You've probably already done a good amount of this.

Comment: Oh yes Kleezy, after posting this I did much more testing, here is an update to that jsfiddle with more examples, and I too have gotten it to go away but in very specific situations that most likely wouldn't meed the design needs of many projects.
[http://jsfiddle.net/kGST9/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/kGST9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this post and have a similar bug with border radius and different width to height ratios of the divs.  I'm not using different sized borders, but different colors.

If I have a border radius and border-color: red blue blue red, the left border gets a strip of blue in it depending on the size.  Only in Web-Kit browsers it seems, and I cant seem to find any work around. I guess its a bug, unless you have found a solution.

Put up my own jsfiddle with my issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/6xUNr/

Comment: It is in fact a bug. I bug report has been filed with Webkit.org, where I have commented on the bug and added my test cases. You can view the bug report at: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72120